# Split within in matrix

Tags: equations, matrices, split

I have a long equation formed of matrices and I wish to split it into two lines. However, when I use split, the first term in the equation (first matrix) disappears.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
    x(k+1) \\ 
    x(k+2) \\ 
    x(k+3) \\ 
    \vdots \\ 
    x(k+N_p)
\end{bmatrix}}_\let\scriptstyle\textstyle
\substack{\overrightarrow{x(k+1)}}}&=\underbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
     A \\ 
     A^2 \\ 
     A^3 \\ 
     \vdots \\ 
     A^{N_p}
    \end{bmatrix}}_\textstyle
    \begin{array}{c}
    F_x
    \end{array}
  }
    & x(k)
    +
    \underbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
     B    & 0  & 0 & \hdots & 0\\
     AB   & B  & 0 & \hdots & 0\\ 
     A^2B & AB & B & \hdots & 0\\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
     A^{N_p-1}B & A^{N_p-2}B & A^{N_p-3}B  & \hdots & B
    \end{bmatrix}}_\textstyle
    \begin{array}{c}
    H_x
    \end{array}
  }
    &
  \underbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
     u(k) \\ 
     u(k+1) \\ 
     u(k+2) \\ 
     \vdots \\ 
     u(k+N_p-1)
    \end{bmatrix}}_\let\scriptstyle\textstyle
    \substack{\overrightarrow{u(k)}}} 
    \\
&\qquad\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
F    & 0  & 0 & \hdots & 0\\
AF   & F  & 0 & \hdots & 0\\ 
A^2F & AF & F & \hdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
A^{N_p-1}F & A^{N_p-2}F & A^{N_p-3}F  & \hdots & F
\end{bmatrix}}_\textstyle
\begin{array}{c}
    T
\end{array}
}
    &
  \underbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
     D(k) \\ 
     D(k+1) \\ 
     D(k+2) \\ 
     \vdots \\ 
     D(k+N_p-1)
    \end{bmatrix}}_\let\scriptstyle\textstyle
    \substack{\overrightarrow{D(k)}}}
    +
    \underbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
     I \\ 
     I+A \\ 
     I+A+A^2 \\ 
     \vdots \\ 
     I+A+A^2+\hdots+A^{N_p-1}
    \end{bmatrix}}_\textstyle
    \begin{array}{c}
    F_x
    \end{array}
  }
x(k)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your example produces errors relating to spurious `}` symbols. I suggest fixing those first. Also, the subscript `\let\scriptstyle\textstyle` looks extremely dubious. What is that meant to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `multline*` environment instead of nested `equation*`/`split` environments. I would also greatly simplify the structure of the second argument of each of the many `\underbrace` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set paper size and margins suitably
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{old-arrows} % optional -- for smaller arrowheads
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\vphantom{\overrightarrow{x(k+1)}}} % define a typographic strut

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\underbrace{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x(k+1) \\ 
    x(k+2) \\ 
    x(k+3) \\ 
    \vdots \\ 
    x(k+N_p)
 \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle \overrightarrow{x(k+1)}}
=\underbrace{
   \begin{bmatrix}
     A \\ 
     A^2 \\ 
     A^3 \\ 
     \vdots \\ 
     A^{N_p}
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle F_x\mystrut}
   x(k)
   +
 \underbrace{
   \begin{bmatrix}
     B    & 0  & 0 & \hdots & 0\\
     AB   & B  & 0 & \hdots & 0\\ 
     A^2B & AB & B & \hdots & 0\\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
     A^{N_p-1}B & A^{N_p-2}B & A^{N_p-3}B  & \hdots & B
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle H_x\mystrut}
 \underbrace{
   \begin{bmatrix}
     u(k) \\ 
     u(k+1) \\ 
     u(k+2) \\ 
     \vdots \\ 
     u(k+N_p-1)
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle \overrightarrow{u(k)}}
   \\  % end of first row
   + % I think a "+" is needed here
 \underbrace{
  \begin{bmatrix}
      F    & 0  & 0 & \hdots & 0\\
      AF   & F  & 0 & \hdots & 0\\ 
      A^2F & AF & F & \hdots & 0\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
      A^{N_p-1}F & A^{N_p-2}F & A^{N_p-3}F  & \hdots & F
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle T\mystrut}
 \underbrace{
   \begin{bmatrix}
     D(k) \\ 
     D(k+1) \\ 
     D(k+2) \\ 
     \vdots \\ 
     D(k+N_p-1)
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle \overrightarrow{D(k)}}
   +
 \underbrace{
   \begin{bmatrix}
     I \\ 
     I+A \\ 
     I+A+A^2 \\ 
     \vdots \\ 
     I+A+A^2+\hdots+A^{N_p-1}
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle F_x\mystrut}
   x(k)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors are mainly in the mysterious `_\textstyle` or the even worse `_\let\scriptstyle\textstyle` commands that just produce weird errors.

I'd adopt a different strategy that takes a bit more space, but is clearer for the reader.

I also try to fix some inconsistencies: there are two different `F_x` matrices and `x(k)` doesn't have the arrow, which it should.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\overrightarrow{x(k+1)}=
F_x \overrightarrow{x(k)}+
H_x\overrightarrow{u(k)}+
T\overrightarrow{D(k)}+
G_x\overrightarrow{x(k)}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\overrightarrow{x(k)}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x(k) \\ 
    x(k+1) \\ 
    x(k+2) \\ 
    \vdots \\ 
    x(k+N_p-1)
  \end{bmatrix}
\!,\;
\overrightarrow{u(k)}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    u(k) \\ 
    u(k+1) \\ 
    u(k+2) \\ 
    \vdots \\ 
    u(k+N_p-1)
  \end{bmatrix}
\!,\;
\overrightarrow{D(k)}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    D(k) \\ 
    D(k+1) \\ 
    D(k+2) \\ 
    \vdots \\ 
    D(k+N_p-1)
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{align*}
F_x&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A \\ 
    A^2 \\ 
    A^3 \\ 
    \vdots \\ 
    A^{N_p}
  \end{bmatrix}
\!,\quad
G_x=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    I \\ 
    I+A \\ 
    I+A+A^2 \\ 
    \vdots \\ 
    I+A+A^2+\dots+A^{N_p-1}
  \end{bmatrix}
\!,
\\[1ex]
H_x&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    B    & 0  & 0 & \dots & 0\\
    AB   & B  & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 
    A^2B & AB & B & \dots & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
    A^{N_p-1}B & A^{N_p-2}B & A^{N_p-3}B  & \dots & B
  \end{bmatrix}
\!,
\\[1ex]
T&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    F    & 0  & 0 & \dots & 0\\
    AF   & F  & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 
    A^2F & AF & F & \dots & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
    A^{N_p-1}F & A^{N_p-2}F & A^{N_p-3}F  & \dots & F
  \end{bmatrix}
\!.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]